# Why won't my iPhone 4S let me turn on the wifi?

Tags: ios, network, wifi, iphone, settings

When I go to `Settings` then to `Wifi`, I cannot turn it `On`.

I had read in another question I should `Reset Network Settings` but that did not seem to help.

Does anyone have any idea what I could do?